# Mercurial: Include secret changesets in bundle?

Tags: mercurial, bundle, dvcs, mercurial-phases

Using Mercurial, how can I bundle all changesets not known to be in another repository, *including* secret changesets?

I know `bundle`'s `--base` option happens to include secret changesets, but I don't want the `--base` behavior. (And it seems unusually weird that secret changesets are *always* included with `--base` but are *never* included without it. Shouldn't there be a separate option?)

FYI, I commonly want to make a backup of all changesets which are only in my local repo before attempting a potentially dangerous history rewrite.

Comment: `hg help phases`  - secret changesets are neither pushed, pulled, or cloned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `hg bundle` will normally exclude secret changesets. This is because it's just running the equivalent of `hg outgoing` and bundling these changesets.

So some work-arounds:

- If you know that you have at least one draft or public outgoing changeset as an ancestor of your secret changesets, then you can use

  ```
  $ hg bundle --base "parents(outgoing())"
  ```

  to get what you want. The `outgoing()` revset will pick the missing draft and public changesets and `parents(outgoing()` will be suitable bases. Since you use `--base` you get all descendants (public, draft, and secret) from these bases.
- You could temporarily make your secret changesets draft, bundle, and then mark them secret again:

  ```
  $ secret=$(hg log --template "{rev} " -r "secret()"); \
    hg phase -d $secret; \
    hg bundle out.hg; \
    hg phase -f -s $secret
  ```

  (I use Zsh and there I had to use `${=secret}` instead of `$secret` because Zsh doesn't do word splitting on parameter expansion by default.)

  It's important to chain the commands with `;` instead of `&&` since you'll want to reset the phases regardless of what happens in the `hg bundle` call — passing wrong parameters to `hg bundle` should not mean that you lose all the information about the secret changesets. Note also that since secret changesets only have secret descendants, there's no information loss with this technique.

  You can turn this into a shell alias:

  ```
  [alias]
  bundle-all = !secret=$(hg log --template "{rev} " -r "secret()");
               hg phase -d $secret;
               hg bundle $@;
               hg phase -f -s $secret
  ```

  The `$@` is expanded by Mercurial before the alias is invoked and this lets you insert the necessary arguments for `hg bundle`.

Note that phase information cannot be stored in bundles — the bundle format has not been changed to accommodate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is at least one public changeset, you can use this:

```
hg bundle -r "not public()" --base public()
```

OTOH, that won't work if there are no public changesets, use this instead:

```
hg bundle -r "not public()" --base null
```

The problem with Martin's answer is that it relies on outgoing, which in turn relies on a direct connection to the push repo. If you don't always have an internet connection to that repo, these methods work well for me. It's also somewhat simpler than the phase dance.

One test for whether there are any public changesets is to capture the output of:

```
hg log -r public() -l 1 --template "{rev}"
```

and test its length, or the presence of [0-9].